# Responsive Image Maps

Tags: html, css, imagemap

Hi I have this HTML code for an image map, the parts of the image are clicked they do something. But when the screen size is changed the image shrinks thanks to my CSS but the image coords stay the same, is there any way to make an responsive image map so when the screen size is changed so will the image map. no jquery please. This I my current code.

```
HTML
<div class="Wrapper2">
    <div class="Title-Context-Box">
                    <img src="ResturantPic/img1.jpg" alt="" width="98%" height="690" usemap="#Map" />
                        <map name="Map" id="Map">
                            <area alt="" title="Table1" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="10,466,56,450,27,446,0,455" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table2" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="42,436,88,441,116,431,75,427" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table3" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="99,424,127,428,156,420,129,414" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table4" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="170,411,179,411,186,409,196,408,203,405,199,402,193,397,180,398,170,398,164,401,163,410" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table5" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="253,425,215,422,222,407,253,407" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table6" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="148,457,126,467,115,488,127,501,145,507,171,507,188,498,218,492,237,476,239,455,229,446,203,441,179,439,152,440,137,446,130,455" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table7" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="339,399,340,412,371,413,367,393" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table8" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="346,442,351,459,398,460,398,446" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table9" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="348,466,350,502,438,501,415,463" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table10" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="492,445,520,464,575,462,544,436" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table11" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="572,431,622,451,656,439,597,414" />
                            <area alt="" title="Table12" onclick="alert('You are clicking on 2');" shape="poly" coords="533,465,560,513,657,498,608,465" />
                        </map>
                    <br>
    </div>
</div>

CSS

.Wrapper2 {      /* My Wrapper CSS*/
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: auto;
    width: 55%;
    border: thin solid #000000;
    align-content:center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.Title-Context-Box {      /* My Title Text Styling Content Box CSS*/
    font-family:Century Gothic;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: auto;
    width: 98%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Check out the [image-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-map) plugin. It works with Javascript, Node, and jQuery

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently html code to do what you're wanting. If you resize the image using css, then the coordinates will no longer line up. This is one limitation with image maps.

Alternatively you could try CSS sprites, or create an image map using dynamic javascript.